# Regex for searching for tags in docx files

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to use Gembox.Document to search a docx file for a tag and to retrieve the value held within the tag. The tag will always be `<!` and `!>`, for example, `<!sometexthere!>` will return sometexthere.

However, I can't get my regex to work properly - I've got the below.

```
var pattern = Regex.Escape("<!(.*?)!>");
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `var res = Regex.Match(s, @"<!(.*?)!>").Groups[1].Value;`?

Comment: Thanks for the help, it does return the first tag. I can't seem to add the global flag and manage to keep it working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the values you need use `Regex.Matches` instead of the `Regex.Escape`:

```
var res = Regex.Matches(s, @"<!(.*?)!>")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(s => s.Groups[1].Value)
    .ToList();
```

The `Regex.Escape` is only used to escape literal strings to be used inside regular expression patterns, e.g. `.` will become `\.` to match a literal dot symbol. `Regex.Match` searches for a single match, while `Regex.Matches` will return all non-overlapping matches. Since you need just Group 1 value, the `Select` clause is quite handy here and `.Select(s => s.Groups[1].Value)` returns just those values that are captured with Group 1 in the pattern.

See this [online C# demo](http://ideone.com/oOgOrb)